# type *types.Transaction has no field or method AsMessage)

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

I am following

> https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-development-with-go-book/tree/master/en/transaction-query

Complete code

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
    "log"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
)

func transactions() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://cloudflare-eth.com")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    blockNumber := big.NewInt(5671744)
    block, err := client.BlockByNumber(context.Background(), blockNumber)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, tx := range block.Transactions() {
        fmt.Println(tx.Hash().Hex())        // 0x5d49fcaa394c97ec8a9c3e7bd9e8388d420fb050a52083ca52ff24b3b65bc9c2
        fmt.Println(tx.Value().String())    // 10000000000000000
        fmt.Println(tx.Gas())               // 105000
        fmt.Println(tx.GasPrice().Uint64()) // 102000000000
        fmt.Println(tx.Nonce())             // 110644
        fmt.Println(tx.Data())              // []
        fmt.Println(tx.To().Hex())          // 0x55fE59D8Ad77035154dDd0AD0388D09Dd4047A8e

        chainID, err := client.NetworkID(context.Background())
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(chainID)

        if msg, err := tx.AsMessage(types.NewEIP155Signer(chainID)); err == nil {
            fmt.Println(msg.From().Hex()) // 0x0fD081e3Bb178dc45c0cb23202069ddA57064258
        }

        receipt, err := client.TransactionReceipt(context.Background(), tx.Hash())
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(receipt.Status) // 1
    }

    blockHash := common.HexToHash("0x9e8751ebb5069389b855bba72d94902cc385042661498a415979b7b6ee9ba4b9")
    count, err := client.TransactionCount(context.Background(), blockHash)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for idx := uint(0); idx < count; idx++ {
        tx, err := client.TransactionInBlock(context.Background(), blockHash, idx)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(tx.Hash().Hex()) // 0x5d49fcaa394c97ec8a9c3e7bd9e8388d420fb050a52083ca52ff24b3b65bc9c2
    }

    txHash := common.HexToHash("0x5d49fcaa394c97ec8a9c3e7bd9e8388d420fb050a52083ca52ff24b3b65bc9c2")
    tx, isPending, err := client.TransactionByHash(context.Background(), txHash)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(tx.Hash().Hex()) // 0x5d49fcaa394c97ec8a9c3e7bd9e8388d420fb050a52083ca52ff24b3b65bc9c2
    fmt.Println(isPending)       // false
}
```

I get this error:

> ./transactions.go:40:21: tx.AsMessage undefined (type
> *types.Transaction has no field or method AsMessage) failed to build, error: exit status 1

Any advice how to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
The good package is:
`import "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/types"`

and the supported transaction type is: `NewLondonSigner()`

Overall, the code will be:

```
import "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/types"
// your code here
if from, err := types.Sender(types.NewLondonSigner(chainID), tx); err == nil {
    fmt.Println(from.Hex()) // 0x0fD081e3Bb178dc45c0cb23202069ddA57064258
}
```

Comment: It is probably better for most cases to use types.LatestSignerForChainID instead of types.NewLondonSigner.

Also, there is no "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/types" only "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types" (maybe got changed since u answered the question) which works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

`AsMessage` method has been removed from `types.Transaction` in newer versions of the `go-ethereum`, use the `types.Sender` instead.

first be sure to import the good package

```
import "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
```

then replace this line

```
if msg, err := tx.AsMessage(types.NewEIP155Signer(chainID)); err == nil {
    fmt.Println(msg.From().Hex()) // 0x0fD081e3Bb178dc45c0cb23202069ddA57064258
```

}

with

```
if from, err := types.Sender(types.NewEIP155Signer(chainID), tx); err == nil {
    fmt.Println(from.Hex()) // 0x0fD081e3Bb178dc45c0cb23202069ddA57064258
}
```